AssertJ How To Compare Parent Object to a Child Object that casted to The Parent Instance
I have problem on assertJ comparison for the Child object that casted to Parent object.
I just wanted to compare all the properties of the Parent object to the expected value object.
Example
class Dog {
  private String name;
  public Dog(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Puddle {
  private String color;
  public Puddle(String name, String color) {
    super(name);
    this.color = color;
  }
}

Dog constructParentOfChildObject() {
  Puddle puddle = new Puddle("test", "blue");
  return (Dog) puddle;
}

@Test
void testExpectedDogName() {
  Dog actual = constructParentOfChildObject();

  Dog expectedResult = new Dog("test");
  assertThat(actual).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(expectedResult);
}

that example will be failed, caused by
Puddle can't be compared to Dog as Dog does not declare all Puddle fields, it lacks these: [color]

Currently the only answer to do this is to use the .ignoringFields() and I need to add all the child field that need to be ignored, but this do not give a scalable way to the UT. I also already got the idea that I can just create a method that clone the child object to a new parent object that having same value of the fields (but I do not want it this way, like creating a method just to do the UT).
I need a simple and better way to do this.

Presumably, you meant to have class Puddle extends Dog (or even class Poodle extends Dog).  At the moment, you have no inheritance relationship between the two, which means your code won't compile.
I would suggest that you implement equals in Dog but not in Puddle, and AssertJ will use it when you write isEqualTo.

AssertJ is completely correct in that case. A puddle can never be equal to a dog as the dog could also be a Terrier. See the documentation of the equals-Method of java.lang.Object for more information about equality of object instances.
Thus, assertThat(expectedResult).usingRecursiveComparison().isEqualTo(actual) would return true while the opposite won't.

Indeed, the recursive comparison gathers the actual fields and then compares them with the expected object, so if your actual object is the parent class, you will only compare the parent class fields

I think the simplest solution would be to implement the method equals(...) in the class Dog and use isEqualTo(...).
class Dog {
    private String name;
    
    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof Dog)) return false;
        Dog dog = (Dog) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, dog.name);
    }
}

// assertion
assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);


One way to go would be either to ignore the subclass fields if you can identify them easily with a regex or restrict the comparison to only the parent class fields.
See https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.26.3/org/assertj/core/api/RecursiveComparisonAssert.html#comparingOnlyFields(java.lang.String...) and https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.26.3/org/assertj/core/api/RecursiveComparisonAssert.html#ignoringFieldsMatchingRegexes(java.lang.String...)
